Docker swarm host randomly becoming unresponsive with "error reading the kernel parameter net.ipv4.vs.conn_reuse_mode"
I have a docker swarm consisting of three Raspberry Pi 5s.
Randomly, one will be unresponsive such that I cannot even SSH into it.
When going into the logs, I find the following:
Oct 11 19:06:48 swarm1 dockerd[846]: time="2024-10-11T19:06:48.674889575+01:00" level=error msg="error reading the kernel parameter net.ipv4.vs.conn_reuse_mode" error="open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/vs/conn_reuse_mode: no such file or directory"
Oct 11 19:06:48 swarm1 dockerd[846]: time="2024-10-11T19:06:48.674966408+01:00" level=error msg="error reading the kernel parameter net.ipv4.vs.expire_nodest_conn" error="open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/vs/expire_nodest_conn: no such file or directory"
Oct 11 19:06:48 swarm1 dockerd[846]: time="2024-10-11T19:06:48.674984704+01:00" level=error msg="error reading the kernel parameter net.ipv4.vs.expire_quiescent_template" error="open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/vs/expire_quiescent_template: no such file or directory"
Oct 11 19:06:48 swarm1 dockerd[846]: time="2024-10-11T19:06:48.675001575+01:00" level=error msg="error reading the kernel parameter net.ipv4.vs.conn_reuse_mode" error="open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/vs/conn_reuse_mode: no such file or directory"
Oct 11 19:06:48 swarm1 dockerd[846]: time="2024-10-11T19:06:48.675016464+01:00" level=error msg="error reading the kernel parameter net.ipv4.vs.expire_nodest_conn" error="open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/vs/expire_nodest_conn: no such file or directory"
Oct 11 19:06:48 swarm1 dockerd[846]: time="2024-10-11T19:06:48.675031390+01:00" level=error msg="error reading the kernel parameter net.ipv4.vs.expire_quiescent_template" error="open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/vs/expire_quiescent_template: no such file or directory"
Oct 11 19:06:48 swarm1 dockerd[846]: time="2024-10-11T19:06:48.675058130+01:00" level=error msg="error reading the kernel parameter net.ipv4.vs.conn_reuse_mode" error="open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/vs/conn_reuse_mode: no such file or directory"
Oct 11 19:06:48 swarm1 dockerd[846]: time="2024-10-11T19:06:48.675075890+01:00" level=error msg="error reading the kernel parameter net.ipv4.vs.expire_nodest_conn" error="open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/vs/expire_nodest_conn: no such file or directory"
Oct 11 19:06:48 swarm1 dockerd[846]: time="2024-10-11T19:06:48.675090593+01:00" level=error msg="error reading the kernel parameter net.ipv4.vs.expire_quiescent_template" error="open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/vs/expire_quiescent_template: no such file or directory"
Oct 11 19:06:48 swarm1 dockerd[846]: time="2024-10-11T19:06:48.675108204+01:00" level=error msg="error reading the kernel parameter net.ipv4.vs.conn_reuse_mode" error="open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/vs/conn_reuse_mode: no such file or directory"
Oct 11 19:06:48 swarm1 dockerd[846]: time="2024-10-11T19:06:48.675123612+01:00" level=error msg="error reading the kernel parameter net.ipv4.vs.expire_nodest_conn" error="open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/vs/expire_nodest_conn: no such file or directory"
Oct 11 19:06:48 swarm1 dockerd[846]: time="2024-10-11T19:06:48.675137186+01:00" level=error msg="error reading the kernel parameter net.ipv4.vs.expire_quiescent_template" error="open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/vs/expire_quiescent_template: no such file or directory"
Oct 11 19:06:48 swarm1 dockerd[846]: time="2024-10-11T19:06:48.784899149+01:00" level=error msg="set bridge default vlan failed" error="failed to enable default vlan on bridge br0: open /sys/class/net/br0/bridge/default_pvid: permission denied"
Oct 11 19:06:49 swarm1 dockerd[846]: time="2024-10-11T19:06:49.183450741+01:00" level=error msg="set bridge default vlan failed" error="failed to enable default vlan on bridge br0: open /sys/class/net/br0/bridge/default_pvid: permission denied"

I did a clean install and re-initialized the swarm, but the issue still keeps occuring.

im thinking hardware fault.

@ChrisBecke it's three new Pis with new Micro SD cards, and it can happen on any one of them
